# REST endpoint, alternative to deprecated "user:password" in the userinfo field

Tags: rest, authentication, url, encryption

According to [RFC 3986 User Information](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.1)

> Use of the format "user:password" in the userinfo field is
> deprecated.  Applications should not render as clear text any data
> after the first colon (":") character found within a userinfo
> subcomponent unless the data after the colon is the empty string
> (indicating no password).

Question:

Can anybody provide an example of encrypted username/password which replaces the deprecated  "user:password" format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication information are simply no longer embedded in the URI, they go in a `Authorization` header.

Could you still create a URI with a secret embedded in it? Yes, but that usually appears in the query parameters.

Only do this if you have an absolute need for it, and make yourself familiar with the risks. At the very least you should probably make sure that these secrets only work exactly once, because as soon as a client requests a uri, that uri is typically stored in a lot of places like logs, caches, etc.

If you can, avoid this and just use the `Authorization` header.